# ¿Como guardar imagen y varios campos en la base de datos laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, formularios

Buenos Días quiero guardar en la base de datos la marca,la imagen y el estado; estoy utilizando

> http://image.intervention.io/

cuando le doy click en guardar me aparece el siguiente error, que puede ser el problema? Gracias por su aporte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi Ruta

```
Route::resource('marca','Controladores\marca');
```

controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $photo = $request->file('image');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($photo)->resize(350,350)->save(public_path('images/marca/' . $filename));
    $imagen->image = $filename;
    $imagen->save();
    return view('Marca.crear');
}
```

Vista:

```
    {!!Form::open(['route'=>'marca.store', 'method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true])!!}
    <div class="form-group form-float">
        <div class="form-line">
           {!!Form::text('nombre',null,['id'=>'nombre','class'=>'form-control'])!!}
           {!!Form::label('name','Marca', array('class' => 'form-label'))!!}
        </div>
    </div>

    {!!Form::label('Imagen')!!}
    {!!Form::file('image', null, array('id' => 'imagen'))!!}
    <br>

    {!!Form::label('Estado')!!}
     <div class="switch">
        <label>INACTIVO
        {!!Form::checkbox('checkbox','value','true')!!}
        <span class="lever">    
        </span>ACTIVO</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" type="submit">REGISTRAR</button> -->
    {!!Form::submit('REGISTRAR',['name'=>'registrar', 'id'=>'registrar', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary waves-effect'])!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: cual es la linea 46 de marca.php

Comment: En el controlador `$imagen` la usas como un objeto pero nunca lo creaste. Me parece que te está faltando crear el modelo.

Answer (score 1):

Según el código de tu controlador, no instanciaste la variable `$imagen`, importa tu modelo e instancia el objeto.

```
$imagen = new Imagen();
$imagen->filename = $filename;
$imagen->save();
```

Suerte!

Comment: El modelo que he citado "new Imagen()" deberia ser el modelo al que le pasaras como valor la ruta de la imagen, es decir, si marca tiene imagen, $marca = new Marca(); $marca->imagen = $filename; $marca->save();